# Jinternalframe with own Jbuttons not functioning

Tags: java, swing, layout, jinternalframe

I have created Jinternal frames and to it i added few buttons.If i make new JInternalFrame("Blah", false, false, false, true); then it does not work properly.eg if one frame is maximized and if try to min another panel then the max panel also gets minimized.However if make all true then it functions properly. My aim was to create my own buttons which will do min/max/restore and close.Please find the code below

```
package Project;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

public class Test5 implements MouseListener {

    private JDesktopPane pane;
public int mouseCount;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test5();
    }
    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;

    public Test5() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                pane = new Test5.DesktopPane() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(400, 400);
                    }
                };
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JInternalFrame newInternalFrame() {
        final JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame("Blah", false, false, false, true);
        inf.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
        inf.setSize(200, 100);
        inf.setVisible(true);

        xpos += 50;
        ypos += 50;

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("panel" + xpos);

        JButton jb = new JButton("_");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("[]");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("X");

        inf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        inf.add(jp);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (inf.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
                        pane.remove(inf);
                        pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                        pane.revalidate();
                        pane.repaint();
                    }
                    inf.pack();
                    inf.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (inf.isMaximum()) {//restore
                        inf.pack();
                    } else {//maximize
                        inf.setMaximum(true);

                    }
                    pane.remove(inf);
                    pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
                    pane.revalidate();
                    pane.repaint();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    inf.dispose();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) inf.getUI()).getNorthPane();
        inf.remove(titlePane);
        return inf;
    }

    public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            int maxLayer = 0;

            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                    maxLayer = Math.max(getLayer(comp), maxLayer);
                }
            }

            maxLayer++;
            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();
                setLayer(icon, maxLayer);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseCount=me.getClickCount();
        if(mouseCount==2)
        {
            System.out.println("clicked"+mouseCount);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("clicked"+mouseCount);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly like to do things the hard way.

This test basically will push any maximized window to the background.  I was able to minimize and restore the other frames without issue, while I had a maximized window.

If you want to move a frame to another layer, simply use `JLayered#setLayer(Component, int)`, you don't need to remove and add them.

```
public class Test5 implements MouseListener {

    private JDesktopPane pane;
    public int mouseCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test5();
    }

    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;

    public Test5() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                pane = new Test5.DesktopPane() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(400, 400);
                    }

                };
                pane.add(newInternalFrame(), 10);
                pane.add(newInternalFrame(), 10);
                pane.add(newInternalFrame(), 10);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public JInternalFrame newInternalFrame() {
        final JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame("Blah", false, false, false, true);
        inf.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
        inf.setSize(300, 300);
        inf.setVisible(true);

        xpos += 50;
        ypos += 50;

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("panel" + xpos);

        JButton jb = new JButton("_");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("[]");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("X");

        inf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        inf.add(jp);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    inf.setIcon(true);
//                    if (inf.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
//                        pane.remove(inf);
//                        pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
//                        pane.revalidate();
//                        pane.repaint();
//                    }
//                    inf.pack();
//                    inf.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    inf.setMaximum(!inf.isMaximum());
                    if (inf.isMaximum()) {
                        ((JLayeredPane)inf.getParent()).setLayer(inf, 0);
                    } else {
                        ((JLayeredPane)inf.getParent()).setLayer(inf, 10);
                    }
//                    if (inf.isMaximum()) {//restore
//                        inf.pack();
//                    } else {//maximize
//                        inf.setMaximum(true);
//
//                    }
//                    pane.remove(inf);
//                    pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
//                    pane.revalidate();
//                    pane.repaint();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Container parent = inf.getParent();
                inf.dispose();
                parent.remove(inf);
                //                try {
                //                    inf.dispose();
                //                } catch (Exception ex) {
                //                    ex.printStackTrace();
                //                }

            }

        });


//        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) inf.getUI()).getNorthPane();
//        inf.remove(titlePane);
        return inf;
    }

    public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            int maxLayer = 0;

            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                    maxLayer = Math.max(getLayer(comp), maxLayer);
                }
            }

            maxLayer++;
            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();
                setLayer(icon, maxLayer);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseCount = me.getClickCount();
        if (mouseCount == 2) {
            System.out.println("clicked" + mouseCount);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("clicked" + mouseCount);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

By the way, this...

```
BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) inf.getUI()).getNorthPane();
inf.remove(titlePane);
```

Will generate a `NullPointerException` under the MacOS

**Updated with bug information**

There is a "bug" in the Windows Look & Feel implementation of the `DesktopManager` that wants to restore all maximized windows when ever another window is iconinfied.

A simple work around is to use the `DefaultDesktopManager` instead.

When you create the `JDesktopPane`, use this...

```
pane.setDesktopManager(new DefaultDesktopManager());
```

Before you add anything to it...

Comment: +1 very nice.... and for *Will generate a NullPointerException under the MacOS*  good to know

Comment: @MadProgrammer with reference to the above code,Initially all are in normal forms,then I min panel50 then max panel100.So panel100 got max and it also conatins panel150(in original postion) So to min panel150 i hit the - button but unfortunately panel100 went to its initial state

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i have went throgh the docs you have refered but i do not find anything relevent to my question.Thanks for your suggestion and where are you from?

Comment: None of the frames should ever "contain" each other.  With the way I have the example set up, all maximized frames are sent to the lowest level, so that the other frames appear on top of them. This is the nature of layered panes.  I went through your scenario and had no problems

Comment: Added your scenario to the answer to demonstrate that it works for me.

Comment: Why does it happen in my computer

Comment: I just tested it on Windows 7 and in fact, you are right, it doesn't work.  You might remember I had a disscusion with another poster about changing the `DesktopManager` and mentioned a bug in the Windows implementation?  Guess what?  You found the bug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24613/discussion-between-madprogrammer-and-sukant)

Comment: I posted a bug fix. My apologies for not believing you, I should have realized you might have hit the Windows `DesktopManager` bug...I have phased those six weeks out of my memory...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are genius ,this is an awesome answer and its working too.Thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer how many years of experience do you have in swing?

Comment: I've been using Swing since Java 1.3, somewhere around 1999 ... Ah, I feel old ;P

Comment: @MadProgrammer apart from swing what else do you know?

Comment: Have some c/c++, but its been years, HTML (but that's more design) JavaScript and an assortment of scripting, pascal, SQL

Comment: @MadProgrammer where do you live?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i Would like to visit Australia well see in the above code it works fine but i have a new query.When i want to max one then other frames are also visible(in the original state). Can it be possible to hide those as well

Comment: In theory, you could request all the frames from the desktop pane and minimise all the frames that isn't equal to the current frame.

Comment: @MadProgrammer After all the frames are minimized and to get back to the max/normal size one has to double click on the min frame.So for this i did titlePane.addMouseListner() and in the actionperformed i have used the codes for max(from the above code )But its not functioning

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you give some ideas how to max frame to limited area.For example two frames are minimized and when you want to max the third one then the frame is extended till bottom(looking as if max frame contains these min frames). The maximum height should be till the minimized frame.The max frame should not go beyond that